# Dell Optiplex 780 Upgrade

Tags: cpu, gpu, dell-optiplex

I've read multiple posts that explain issues with upgrading a Dell Optiplex 780, mainly due to issues such as a low wattage power supply and low gigabytes of RAM. What I would like to know is, what limits on upgrading could be removed if I upgraded my PSU/RAM.

My original specs:

CPU Intel E8400
RAM 4 GB DDR3
Hard Drive  320 GB
PSU 305W

After upgrading:

CPU Intel E8400
RAM 8-16GB DDR3
Hard Drive  1 TB
PSU 430-500W

If I would need to upgrade the motherboard to support higher end graphics cards, I may be able to do so.

Comment: Optiplex 780 is a small form factor (SFF) PC, it may not fit a regular-sized motherboard. I suspect that PSU is non-standard too and can't be simply replaced with an off-the-shelf unit.

Comment: There's also a full sized varient it seems https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/optiplex_780_tech_guidebook_en.pdf

Comment: To be honest, if you are thinking of upgrading a ~7 year old PC with a new motherboard you would probably be better off just building/buying a new PC. Regardless, https://pcpartpicker.com/list/ is quite good at checking if your selected components are compatible.

Comment: You shouldn't need to upgrade your PSU if you are just adding ram. With regards to adding a GPU, if it doesn't have a external power connector the power supply should be fine.

Comment: I was feeling a bit skeptical about the PSU, and I thought that I might just have to start with a fresh build. I already have a computer built on pcpartpicker, but this was just another option that I had available. The performance wouldn't be great, but it would save me some money I thought. Might just have to build my own from scratch.

Comment: If you able to shop on ebay, you can get there complete computer with i5 cpu for around $100-120 or i7 for ~250. I think it would be better investment than upgrading your current configuration, you will spend more on upgrading than you can get cheaper with much more powerful PC. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Well, I took the grandfather's axe approach to PC building. I started with an old dell from a dumpster and gradually replaced parts. I can relate to this *somewhat*

Answer (score 3):

Its an older system. The benefits you'd get from a high end video card would be limited.

Lets talk bottlenecks.

If its anything like the dell 530 I've worked with in the past, it would have a PSU with only SATA connectors. *Desktop model* Dells of that vintage *fortunately* use standard ATX PSUs and upgrading those would be an option. Dell typically has 3 sizes of the same model with variable levels of upgradability so that matters.

If you're running windows 7, or even 10, *get an SSD*. Its the single best upgrade you can do.

I believe the most you can upgrade the system is 8gb with 4 2gb DIMMS. [While there are forum posts that claim you can go up to 16gb](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1957376/dell-optiplex-e8400-intel-core2duo-16gb-ram.html) - Its not officially supported, and if it dosen't work, well, you would need to upgrade it anyway.

Looking at the stock configuration, *any* modern midrange card would work great. [Hot Hardware](http://hothardware.com/reviews/gpu-redux-can-old-dualcores-drive-a-modern-graphics-card) threw in a gforce 660 (which is *about* 4 generations old) and had a big improvement in performance. I certainly don't see the point in throwing in a real high end card, like a 1080 or Titan into such a machine. *Personally* I'd go for the bottom end of decent video cards, or something slightly older, like say a nvidia gforce 750 (which runs off the PCI bus - or anything ending with a 50 anyway) or the aformentioned 660.

Comment: The 16gb of RAM was most likely to happen if I just had spare cash to spend, so 8 was really what I was planning to get. I had no plans of buying a card that was top of the line for this machine, but do you think my best bet is with the 750ti? I've heard it come up a few times, but someone else suggested a 1050ti Mini. I don't really know if that would be a good combination though, since my processor might not be able to keep up. Any input?

Comment: For specific hardware recommendations - try the hardware recommendations stackexchange site. I tend to go nvidia mid to high end, while in your case a medium-low end card makes sense, and you could go AMD potentially

Comment: Good advice.  My tower 780 with full RAM and an SSD makes a great Windows 7 64-bit system.  It gets a bit confused when you try to use the BIOS-based RAID, but other than that it is nice to get older hardware at decent prices.  I run a large HDMI monitor from the Dport and occasionally add a VGA for graphic design using a Bamboo sketchpad..  The only speed bump is that the system always boots directly to the VGA before Windows loads.